# sfdx import failure ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: salesforcedx, import

I'm trying to import data in a scratch org but I'm always getting the error

```
andresbrav-ltm2:sfdx-out local.user$ sfdx force:data:tree:import --targetusername test-user@example.com --plan export-demo-Broker__c-Property__c-plan.json 
ERROR running force:data:tree:import:  ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/local.user/.local/share/sfdx/client/node_modules/salesforce-alm/schemas/dataImportPlanSchema.json'
```

I have generated the json data files and the json plan file with the sfdx export command, I have tried also with the files from the git repository for the trailhead course DreamHouse but it always tries to find this file .../dataImportPlanSchema.json that is not the plan file I'm sending.

Did anyone face this issue and know how to make the import command work with a plan to insert related tables?.

Comment: There's been a rash of random errors lately. Have you tried the following commands: `sfdx update` and `sfdx plugins:install salesforcedx@latest`?

Comment: There has been a new release of the CLI so it is possibly a version error. Best to try updating as @sfdcfox suggests.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox, the command: ```sfdx update and sfdx plugins:install salesforcedx@latest``` did the magic

Comment: @sfdcfox Thank you very much! It helped me too in a bit different situation!

Comment: Had the same issue and doing "sfdx update and sfdx plugins:install salesforcedx@latest" killed my CLI... ERROR running force:org:create:  Cannot read property 'create' of undefined

Answer (score 2):

This was a bug in 45.8.1. We fixed this in a patch, 45.8.2.
https://developer.salesforce.com/media/salesforce-cli/releasenotes.html

Also, you do not need to run `sfdx plugins:install salesforcedx@latest` as the latest version of salesforcedx is already bundled with the cli. Just `sfdx update` is enough. I would recommend uninstalling salesforcedx as a user plugin and just using the one bundled with the CLI. To do so, just run `sfdx plugins:uninstall salesforcedx`. You only need to install it as a user plugin to pin to a specific version that isn't latest, see https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_install_cli.htm# for more info.

To verify you are using the core salesforcedx version, you can run `sfdx plugins --core` and you will see the *(core)* next to salesforcedx.