# Unable to run sfdx command after installing Salesforce CLI

Tags: salesforcedx

```
Error: Cannot find module '../dist/versions'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> 

(C:\Users\Demo\AppData\Local\sfdx\client\bin\sfdx.js:7:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
```

Comment: FYI https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/92.

Comment: ```sfdx update and sfdx plugins:install salesforcedx@latest``` Try this commans, it may help you as it helped me in mostly similar problem. Source: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/255812/sfdx-import-failure-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: @MariiaIllarionova error still exists even after running following command.

Comment: Thanks for the response .Now sfdx command is working by deleting the client folder here (C:\Users\Demo\AppData\Local\sfdx\client) .

Answer (score -1):

By deleting the client folder located somewhere at C:\Users\Demo\AppData\Local\sfdx\client, it worked. I was getting the same error of 'Cannot find module'. This client folder contained some node js files.

Comment: running the commands sfdx update and sfdx plugins:install salesforcedx@latest didnt resolve the issue, but deleting the client folder and then running the commands resolved the issue

Comment: Deleting client directory helped me.